# In Power Apps set value of second date picker when first changed within a gallery

Tags: datepicker, powerapps

I have a gallery control on an add form to allow users to input any number of weeks from the year (for vacation requests). The gallery row item, has 5 date pickers for Monday - Friday, and I have data validation in place to ensure Tuesday follows Monday, and so on. They don't have to request/select all days of any week. However, they would like to be able to select the Monday date, then auto-populate Tuesday-Friday for the week.

I have tried this two ways, each not working.

Any ideas how to facilitate this?

1. Added a button to the row to fill the week.

```
btn_FillWeek.OnSelect: dp_Tuesday_2.SelectedDate = DateAdd(dp_Monday_2.SelectedDate, 1, TimeUnit.Days);
dp_Wednesday_2.SelectedDate = DateAdd(dp_Monday_2.SelectedDate, 2, TimeUnit.Days);
```

This doesn't do anything. No errors, but just doesn't do anything.

2. Set the DefaultDate of Tuesday-Friday

```
dp_Monday.OnChange: UpdateContext({varMondayDate:dp_Monday.SelectedDate})
dp_Tuesday.DefaultDate: DateAdd(varMondayDate, 1, TimeUnit.Days)
dp_Wednesday.DefaultDate: DateAdd(varMondayDate, 2, TimeUnit.Days).....
```

This works for row 1, but fails for additional rows as varMondayDate is not row unique.